# Accessing the currently selected element's content in a html(val) statement in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, replace

I have a several **links** whose text content I'd like to replace with a automatically generated image based on the text content.

So currently it looks like this:

```
<a href="blabla" class="mLink">
<span class="mText">The Text in Question</span>
</a>
```

and I would like to have either

```
<a href="blabla" class="mLink">
<img src="/ImageTextHandler.ashx?message=The+Text+in+Question" alt="The Text in Question"/>
</a>
```

or

```
<a href="blabla" class="mLink">
<span class="mText">
    <img src="/ImageTextHandler.ashx?message=The+Text+in+Question" alt="The Text in Question"/>
</span>
</a>
```

How do I access the element in question inside a .replaceWith or .html so that I can get the text content?

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
$(".mLink").each(function (i) {

   var thisText = $(this).find(".mText").text();
   $(this).html("<img src='/ImageTextHandler.ashx?
         message=" + thisText + "' alt='" + thisText + "'/>");

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Using localized selectors

```
$(".mLink").each(function() {
    var text = $("span", this).text();
    $("span", this).replaceWith("<img src='/ImageTextHandler.ashx?message="+
                                  text+"' alt='"+text+"' />");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function() {    
    var mySpan = $('a.mLink span.mText');
    var text = mySpan.text();
    var link = text.split(' ').join('+');

    mySpan.replaceWith($("<img src='/ImageTextHandler.ashx?message=" + link + "' alt='" + text + "'/>"));
});
```

**[Working Demo here](http://jsbin.com/aqege)**

Code from demo

```
$(function() {

    $('#button').click(function() {

      $('a.mLink span.mText').each(function() {    
        var text = $(this).text();
        var link = text.split(' ').join('+');
        $(this).replaceWith($("<img src='/ImageTextHandler.ashx?message=" + link + "' alt='" + text + "'/>"));
      });

    });
});
```

Comment: nice conversion to link format. But will this work for several links? Won't they all end up the same?

Comment: Not if you perform the operation on each matched element as in the example :)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this...

```
$(".mText").each(function(){
  var url = "/ImageTextHandler.ashx?message=" + escape($(this).text());
  var image = $("<img>");
  image.attr("src") = url;
  image.attr("alt") = $(this).text();
  $(this).text("");
  $(this).append(image);
});
```

Comment: you've mismatched your quotes should be $("<img>");

Comment: Curse those fat fingers :-)
Thanks for that - I've corrected the error.